# IdentityFile ignored in ssh configuration

Tags: linux, git, ssh

My `ssh` configuration inside `/root/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_api
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_ui
```

I use these keys to be able to clone GitHub repositories. However, only the first `IdentityFile` (API) works. For the second, it says `Repository not found` as I start cloning. When I swap the configuration like:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_ui
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_api
```

This way I can clone the UI, but not the API. As a consequence, I see that the keys are correct, but the second IdentityFile is always ignored. What could the problem be?

I cannot use *ssh-add* because I configure `ssh` inside a Dockerfile and ssh-agent is not running when the container is build.

Comment: What if you just load both keys into an ssh agent...does that change the behavior at all?

Comment: @larsks how would I do this with existing keys?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question...an ssh agent always works with existing keys.  You add them using `ssh-add`, assuming that you have the agent set up correctly.

Comment: @larsks just figured out that I cannot use ssh-add. Check my update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys

> Deploy keys only grant access to a single repository. More complex
>   projects may have many repositories to pull to the same server

So I dropped using deploy keys. Instead I created an ssh key that allows access to all of my private repositories. This way I have a single IdentityFile.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any other keys besides the two you've listed in the question? The OpenSSH server `sshd` will drop a client after too many failed authentication attempts. If you have enough keys, your client may be trying all of them and being dropped before it gets through all of the keys you've listed. Running `ssh` with the `-v` parameter will show which keys ssh tries to use to authenticate.

The [sshd_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) parameter `MaxAuthTries` determines how many times a client can attempt to authenticate. The default is 6.

If this is the problem, you may be able to avoid it by setting the [ssh_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) parameter `IdentitiesOnly`. This prevents your client from using identities that didn't come from the ssh configuration files. Another thing to consider is to use more specific `Host` or `Match` directives, so you only apply a key to the specific hosts where the key should be used.